# Lenovo Laptop won't charge above 59%, Elementary Os Freya (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS based I hope)

Tags: power-management, elementary-os, battery

When I had windows I used lenovo energy managment and set the battery to charge up to 60% only as it recommended it to me. Yesterday I switched to Ubuntu and now I have this problem. It would be great if I could fix this without installing windows again.

I don't know what all details you will need. Anyway I am providing this one:

```
acpi -i

Battery 0: Unknown, 59%
Battery 0: design capacity 176 mAh, last full capacity 168 mAh = 95%
Wrong mAh values :/
```

Please let me know what all infos you need?

Regards

Comment: Try to see what vendor tools for your laptop show under Windows for that battery. Power management is a weaker side of Linux, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 0):

It may have nothing to do with your OS. The battery itself may be degraded.